# Bandwidth monitoring with daily quota, user notification

Tags: gratis, windows-10, bandwidth

I'm looking for an open source **or** freeware application that enables bandwidth monitoring, giving notifications, setting **daily quota** such that when 85% of daily quota is used it notifies the user, and at 100% it altogether disables network activity. It should monitor data coming to the computer it is running on.

Similar alternatives I tried are Networx data manager and Bitmeter OS however the former don't allow to disable connection  without me ignoring data in LAN connection.

Comment: It should monitors network data coming to the computer it is running on, right? Not for a whole network of machines?

Comment: Yes, only to the computer it is running on

Comment: Please add that info to your question, comments get deleted.